# How to add values in php?

Tags: php, variables

I thought I had this syntax right, but apparently I don't... here's what I have.

```
    /* Price Calculation */
    if ($stage="1") $price + 1000 = $price;
    if ($stage="2") $price + 2500 = $price;
    if ($stage="3") $price + 5000 = $price;
    if ($chrome=on) $price + 100 = $price;
    if ($bov=on) $price + 200 = $price;
    if ($controller=on) $price + 500 = $price;
    if ($filter=on) $price + 50 = $price;
    print "<br /><u>Total: </u>";
    echo $price;
```

The variables are already declared correctly, so I know it isn't that. The php has a problem with the ='s. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

you should use `==` in condition

```
 if ($stage="1")
```

should be

```
 if ($stage=="1")
```

and adding should be

```
$price = $price + 1000;
```

Your code should be

```
<?php

 /* Price Calculation */
    if ($stage=="1") {
        $price = $price + 1000;
    }
    if ($stage=="2") {
        $price = $price + 2500;
    }
    if ($stage=="3") {
        $price = $price + 5000;
    } 
    if ($chrome==true) {
        $price = $price + 100;
    }
    if ($bov==true) {
        $price = $price + 200;
    }
    if ($controller==true) {
        $price = $price + 500;
    }
    if ($filter==true) {
        $price = $price + 50;
    }
    echo "<br /><u>Total: </u>";
    echo $price;

?>
```

I don't know why you are using **on**. I think, it's a Boolean condition.

Comment: The other part fixed it. I had my equals backwards. Can't believe I overlooked that...

Answer (score 1):

```
    if ($stage=="1") $price = $price + 1000;
    if ($stage=="2") $price = $price + 2500;
    if ($stage=="3") $price = $price + 5000;
    if ($chrome==on) $price = $price + 100;
    if ($bov==on) $price = $price + 200;
    if ($controller==on) $price = $price + 500;
    if ($filter==on) $price = $price + 50;
    print "<br /><u>Total: </u>";
    echo $price;
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are a couple of problems:**

**(1)** 
You are trying to assign the value of `$price` into `$price + number`, which is impossible. Try:

```
$price = $price + number;
```

**(2)**
Use the `==` operator for checking equality, like:

```
if ($stage == "1")
```

A single `=` is the *assignment* operator.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `$price = $price + 100;` or `$price += 100`?

Also, you are mistaking your assignment for equality testing. `=` never meant equality in php---it means assignment (think of it `$price = $price + 100` doesn't make sense it it is equality). To test for equality, use `==` (check your conditions).

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to:

```
if ($stage=="1") 
   $price = $price + 1000;
if ($stage=="2") 
    $price = $price + 2500;
if ($stage=="3") 
    $price = $price + 5000;
if ($chrome==on) 
   $price = $price + 100;
if ($bov==on) 
   $price = $price + 200;
if ($controller==on) 
   $price = $price + 500;
if ($filter==on) 
   $price = $price + 50;

print "<br /><u>Total: </u>";
echo $price;
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `==` for comparison (since `=` is for assignment), consider adding using the [`+=` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) to add values to variables.  Also, while it *works*, many folks consider it bad practice to skip your curly braces.

```
  if ($stage=="1") {
    $price += 1000;
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($stage=="1") $price += 1000;
if ($stage=="2") $price += 2500;
if ($stage=="3") $price += 5000;

if ($chrome=="on") $price += 100;  // if your want to use "on" instead of TRUE, use it as a string
if ($bov=="on") $price += 200;
if ($controller=="on") $price += 500;
if ($filter=="on") $price += 50;
echo "<br /><u>Total: </u>";
echo $price;
```